# R Using index of rows for merging file

Tags: r, merge, row

I'm working with the survival library in R. I used residuals() on a survival object, which nicely outputs the residuals I want.

My question is on how R treats its row indexes.

Here is a sample data set. My goal is to merge them back together.

Data Frame:

```
> 1 - .2
> 2 - .4
> 3 - .6
> 4 - .8
```

Output:

```
> 1 - .2X
> 2 - .4X
> 4 - .8X
```

The output is a subset of the input (some data couldn't be processed). What I'd like is to add this new list back to the original input file to plot and run regressions, etc.

I don't know how to access the row indexes outside of the simple df[number] command. I think my approach to doing this is a bit prehistoric; I write.table() the objects which turns their row number into an actual printed column, and then go back and merge based on this new  key. I feel like there is a smarter way then to write out and read back in the files. Any suggestions on how?

I hope this isn't a duplicate, as I looked around and couldn't quite find a good explanation on row indices.

Edit:

I can add column or row names to a data frame, but this results in a NULL value if done to a one dimensional object (my output file). The one dimensional object just has a subset of rows that I can't access.

> rownames(res)
>
> NULL

Comment: You can add a column containing the rownames: `d$names <- rownames(d)`

Comment: (Edited post to reflect comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an appropriate `data.frame` object out of `res`:

```
res.df <- data.frame(names=names(res), res=res)
```

Then use this as one of the inputs to `merge`.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of creating a new object as proposed above, you can simply use `merge` directly.

Just write:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = 0, by.y = res)
```

The `by.x=0` refers then to the row names of the `df1`.  The `by.y` refers to the row names of df2.  The merge is performed using those as the link.

Answer (score 0):

For the join you can use merge() or join() from the plyr package.

Here is a question regarding both:
[How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

I find join() more intuitive, has the SQL logic and it seems to perform better with large datasets also.